# Multiplication of values in a matrix with its row number

Tags: r

I have nX1 Matrix for example this one:

```
[,1]
[1,]  480
[2,]  483
[3,]  480
[4,]  480
```

and I want to run this function over this matrix:

```
fun_window<-function(x)
{
  ((sin(n*pi)/length(datalist))^2*x;
  n<-n+1 
}
```

here n is row number. in this situation:

```
480 * 1
483 * 2
480 * 3
480 * 4
```

I am invoking my Function with `apply`:

```
s<-apply(df,2,FUN=fun_window)
```

but in my n is always 2. How should I implement this job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `apply` because `sin` is vectorized.  Also, you probably want `sin(n*pi/length(datalist))` rather than `sin(n*pi)/length(datalist)` because if `n` is an integer then `sin(n*pi)` is equal to zero.  Here's what I think you want:

```
s<-df*sin((1:length(df))*pi/length(datalist))^2
```

Answer (score 1):

What's `datalist`?

In any case, you don't actually need to use `apply` and a separate function. You can instead take advantage of the `row` function and vectorization:

```
s <- (sin(row(x)*pi)/length(datalist))^2*x
```

`row` returns a matrix of the same shape as its argument, but with each cell replaced by a row number:

```
x
#      [,1]
# [1,]  480
# [2,]  483
# [3,]  480
# [4,]  480

row(x)
#      [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    2
# [3,]    3
# [4,]    4
```

In your original example, `n` is always 2 because of scoping: the `n` assigned to inside of the function is not the same as the `n` you have defined outside the function. The function assigns its own version, which is then discarded when the function returns. You *could* get around this by using `<<-`, but it's far better to dispense with the function altogether in favor of a safer and more concise approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 datalist * row(datalist)
```